# aligned radio buttons in r Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, widget, radiobuttonlist

In R Shiny I wrote the following script as implementation of multiple grouped radio buttons, where the values of the buttons are shown on top, and the radio buttons of multiple questions are aligned to those button values:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title=HTML("&nbsp;"), windowTitle="Questionaire"),

  cellWidths = c("100%"),
  cellArgs = list(style = "padding: 6px"),

  wellPanel(
    splitLayout(cellWidths = c("25%","10%","10%","10%","10%","10%"),"",
                p("strongly agree"),p("agree"),p("neutral"),p("disagree"),p("strongly disagree")),

    splitLayout(cellWidths = c("25%","10%","10%","10%","10%","10%"),p(strong("The website has a user friendly interface:")), 
                radioButtons("use1", "", "", selected=0, inline = T),
                radioButtons("use2", "", "", selected=0, inline = T),
                radioButtons("use3", "", "", selected=0, inline = T),
                radioButtons("use4", "", "", selected=0, inline = T),
                radioButtons("use5", "", "", selected=0, inline = T)),

    splitLayout(cellWidths = c("25%","10%","10%","10%","10%","10%"),p(strong("The website is easy to navigate:")), 
                radioButtons("nav1", "", "", selected=0, inline = T),
                radioButtons("nav2", "", "", selected=0, inline = T),
                radioButtons("nav3", "", "", selected=0, inline = T),
                radioButtons("nav4", "", "", selected=0, inline = T),
                radioButtons("nav5", "", "", selected=0, inline = T))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In this implementation multiple options per question can be checked. How can the code be changed so that once a user has chosen an option for a question, this choice will be deselected as soon as the user subsequently chooses another option for the same question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this help you out a little, it may still need some tweaking. I reckon the best way to get a grid is to have one radiobutton option for each 'question'. In order to set this to a grid you may have to play around with the CSS settings in tags$style. For example:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

tags$style(".checkbox-inline, .radio-inline {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
width: 20%;} "),

titlePanel(title=HTML("&nbsp;"), windowTitle="Questionaire"),



cellWidths = c("100%"),
cellArgs = list(style = "padding: 6px"),

wellPanel(
    # Introduced div to centre align the headers
    splitLayout(cellWidths = c("25%","10%","10%","10%","10%","10%"),"",
                            div(style="text-align:center", HTML("strongly agree")),
                            div(style="text-align:center", HTML("agree")),
                            div(style="text-align:center", HTML("neutral")),
                            div(style="text-align:center", HTML("disagree")),
                            div(style="text-align:center", HTML("strongly disagree"))),

    splitLayout(cellWidths = c("25%","50%"),
                            p(strong("The website has a user friendly interface:")), 
                            radioButtons("use1", "", choiceValues=1:5, choiceNames=rep("",5),  selected=0, inline = T)
    ),

    splitLayout(cellWidths = c("25%","50%"),
                            p(strong("The website is easy to navigate:")), 
                            radioButtons("nav1", "", choiceValues=1:5, choiceNames=rep("",5), selected=0, inline = T)
    ))
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! But when changing the window so that the height/width ratio changes, the radio buttons are no longer aligned correctly to the five labels shown on top. This is a problem since the users may use screens with different height/width ratios.

Comment: I see what you mean, I have edited my answer so the radio buttons scale with the screen by setting width to 20% in tags$style (100% / 5 for the 5 options) however this introduces a scroll bar I am not sure how to get rid of. Admittedly I am not a HTML expert

Comment: Thanks again, this helps! When adding 'width=90' as parameter to 'radioButtons' the scroll bar disappears when the window is not too narrow.

Comment: True! Although this does add a slight misalignment with the labels. If this bothers you, you can change their cell width to around 9% instead of 10% and it should align better (90% of 100% = 9%) if that makes sense. I did not think this would require so much algebra !